# I am getting error variable Accnew and ACCold does not exist in apex trigger

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex

1. trigger PractiseM on Account (before update) {
2. if (trigger.isBefore && trigger.isUpdate) {
3. ```
      for(Account accNew : trigger.new)
   ```
4. ```
          Account Accold = trigger.oldmap.get(Accnew.Id);
   ```
5. ```
      If (accNew.Name != AccOld.name) {
   ```
6. ```
          accNew.addError ('Please do not change the account name');
   ```
7. ```
      }
   ```
8. }
   9.}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need curly braces. Your for loop in line 3 doesn't have braces so the scope is just line 4 and then you're out of the loop. So line 5 "thinks" you try to use undeclared variables.

Fix the braces and - since your indentation was lying to you - consider using something like Prettier / eslint for code formatting checks?